# Formatting Integers in JTable Column Cells With Commas

Tags: java, swing, jtable, format, number-formatting

I have a Price column that displays integers in plain format like 1000000. I would like to know how can I format it with commas without affecting its value when retrieving with table.getValueAt()?

Is there a method like table.setColumnCellFormat(decimalFormat)?

Comment: What `Class` type are you returning for the column in the `TableModel`? Take a look at [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) and `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance`

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer String.class from the TableModel

Comment: If you can, store them as some kind of number, it will make formatting them much easier

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ohh, it's actually stored as Type Integer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm stuck at here. mytable.getColumn("price").setCellRenderer( ? );

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please guide me further.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Am I doing it right? Should I implement the NumberFormat.getNumberInstance inside new TableCellRenderer or new DefaultTableCellRenderer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a custom `TableCellRenderer` which can format the value the way you need it.  See [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more details

[image: Lots of numbers]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
            for (int index = 10000; index < 11000; index++) {
                model.addRow(new Object[]{index});
            }

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new NumberTableCellRenderer());

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(table));

        }

        public class NumberTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

            public NumberTableCellRenderer() {
                setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
            }

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                if (value instanceof Number) {
                    value = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(value);
                }
                return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So if I want to retrieve the data, I should use model.getValueAt() instead of table.getValueAt() to prevent getting commas right?

Comment: This is super helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should create a custom TableCellRenderer for that column, one that uses a DecimalFormat instance, one that has the `setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true)` called on it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/).

It provides a simple example of how to create a custom renderer by overriding the `setValue(...)` method of the renderer.

Or you can use one of the provided classes which allows you to easily create reusable renderers with different formats.